# Enter Key Event as Tab Key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to know about Enter Key action as Tab Index.

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) 
{
    invocation.target.isPressEnterKey = "TRUE";
    event.keyCode = 9;
}
```

This code is not working when arrive last tab index.

When arrive last tab index, cannot move 
to the first tab index.

But Tab Key is correct. Now problem is the Enter Key event.

Comment: Why do you want to replace Enter key and Tab. Show us some detail.

Comment: This is system requirement.I want to work Enter Key event as Tab key.